# how to add icons inside the circles made by custom painter and text under it with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created my custom timeline using custom painter, now I want to place an icon inside each circle and a caption exactly under each circle. What is the correct way to place these widgets on my timeline? I can't use packages so I have to do using these tools in flutter

Code for timeline itself looks like this:

```
class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..strokeWidth = 8.0
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    const double circleRadius = 20.0;
    const double distanceBetweenCircles = 80.0;

  
    final double centerX = size.width / 2;
    final double centerY = size.height / 2;

 
    final double startX = centerX - 1.5 * distanceBetweenCircles;
    final double startY = centerY;

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(startX, startY), circleRadius, paint);

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(startX + distanceBetweenCircles, startY), circleRadius, paint);

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(startX + 2 * distanceBetweenCircles, startY), circleRadius, paint);

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(startX + 3 * distanceBetweenCircles, startY), circleRadius, paint);

 
    canvas.drawLine(
      Offset(startX + circleRadius, centerY),
      Offset(startX + 3 * distanceBetweenCircles - circleRadius, centerY),
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

and this is a widget inside which I want to control the icons inside the circles and the inscriptions under the circles.

```
class Timeline extends StatelessWidget {
  const Timeline({
    Key? key,

  })  :
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
          painter: MyPainter(
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children:[
            Icon(Icons.add),
            Icon(Icons.add),
            Icon(Icons.add),
            Icon(Icons.add),
          ])
        );
  }
}
```